# Grothendieck group of equivalent categories

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, additive-categories

Let $\Gamma : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ be an equivalence of categories where $\mathcal A$ is an exact category, $\mathcal B$ is an additive full subcategory of the category of $R$-modules for some commutative Noetherian ring $R$ , and $\Gamma$ is an additive functor .

Then is it true that $\Gamma$ induces an isomorphism of Grothendieck groups $K_0(\mathcal A)\cong K_0(\mathcal B)$ ? If this is not true in general, would some extra assumptions on the categories of the functor would make it true ?

Comment: Yes, it is true. An equivalence functor has left and right adjoint (its inverse), and thus preserves the Abelian structure.

Comment: I'll assume you intended to write $K_0$ instead of $G_0$.  For the question to have a meaning, you need to say what short exact sequences in $\cal B$ are to be used in the formation of $K_0(\cal B)$, i.e., to give $\cal B$ the structure of an exact category.

Comment: @Dan Grayson: yeah I guess people do call the Grothendieck group by $K_0$ ... as for $\mathcal B$ , I'm talking all exact sequences with objects in $\mathcal B$ and any morphism of modules are allowed. For my purpose, I also assume $\mathcal B$ is closed under extension and isomorphism

Answer (score 2):

No, not in general. $\mathcal{A}$ could be the same as $\mathcal{B}$ as an additive category (and $\Gamma$ the identity functor), but with a different exact structure. Then there is no reason to expect the Grothendieck groups to be isomorphic.

For example, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category of finitely generated abelian groups with the exact structure given by split short exact sequences, and $\mathcal{B}$ the same category with the exact structure given by all short exact sequences. Then $K_0(\mathcal{B})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, but $K_0(\mathcal{A})$ is free abelian of countable rank.